# "NTLDR is missing Press ctr-Alt-Del to restart" - After formatting a new PC

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I just setup a new PC with Windows XP. After setting it up, I formatted the un-partitioned space to D drive. Now when I power cycle the PC it gives me an error stating"   "NTLDR is missing Press ctr-Alt-Del to restart"  How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the partition number as changed in the boot.ini file, but that's only a guess based in the information you have supplied. The reason this may have happened is if by formatting the the D: drive and thus creating a new disk/partition, the system sees the new volume as higher in the connection chain. So, what used to be disk0 for C: is now disk 1 or what use to be partition 1 for C: is now partition 2.

If you can boot from a CD/DVD/USB or even a floppy so that you can gain access to the Windows System volume (drive C:) you may be able to edit the boot.ini file and restore the system.

The boot.ini file will have a line thate looks like this:

multi(X)disk(Y)rdisk(Z)partition(W)\

The elements you are interested in are (z) and (w) if Windows is installed in the default location the values for (z) and (w) should be 0 and 1 respectively. These values may need changing, see above. If the D: drive is a separate disk, then you may be able to achieve that same thing by changing the boot order in the BIOS.

if the NTLDR file has become corrupt you can try and repair the system by booting from your XP CD and selecting repair during the start-up. this should replace any corrupt files. You can always just copy the file from your XP cd to the root of C:, too.

Answer (score 0):

Windows refers to hard disks and partitions by their numbers, which means that you can't change their order. These references are found not only in boot.ini, but also in the registry itself.

My guess is that you have created a new partition from the unallocated space found **before** the Windows partition, in effect incrementing by one its partition number.

If you wish to avoid reinstalling Windows, the solution would be to move the new partition to **after** the Windows one. The easiest way to do that would be to delete it, returning the space to unallocated, then move the Windows partition so that all unallocated space is consolidated **after** the Windows partition. You may then convert this space to a new partition without negative effects on the Windows partitions numbering.

Answer (score -1):

Boot from the Windows XP cd rom and go into the repair mode. Type the administrator password when prompted. In the command promt type

> COPY X:\I386 C:\
>
> COPY X:\I386\NTDETECT C:\

Where X:\ is your CD\DVD drives path.